# display image size in media library screen

Tags: media, media-library, customization

i'm trying to add image size in media library screen so will be simply to handle images. Anyone does it before me?
Any help appreciated.
Francesco

Comment: [Codex: `add_image_size();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Investigating this Q&A, I ended up assembling a two sortable columns solution (width & height). I posted it in [this other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54267/12615) because there the sortable functionality is being asked... But @Rarst answer and link got me started in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Code based on [Custom Sortable Columns](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html)

```
add_filter('manage_upload_columns', 'size_column_register');

function size_column_register($columns) {

    $columns['dimensions'] = 'Dimensions';

    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_media_custom_column', 'size_column_display', 10, 2);

function size_column_display($column_name, $post_id) {

    if( 'dimensions' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image($post_id)) return;

    list($url, $width, $height) = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id, 'full');

    echo esc_html("{$width}&times;{$height}");
}
```

Comment: Its not sortable as stated, just lists the sizes only

Comment: @iamkingsleyf the question didn't ask for sortable, I merely used linked post as starting point at the time. :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, 
I was looking that for a while.

And for sizes (meaning weight)

```
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'sk_media_columns_filesize' );
/**
 * Filter the Media list table columns to add a File Size column.
 *
 * @param array $posts_columns Existing array of columns displayed in the Media list table.
 * @return array Amended array of columns to be displayed in the Media list table.
 */
function sk_media_columns_filesize( $posts_columns ) {
    $posts_columns['filesize'] = __( 'File Size', 'my-theme-text-domain' );

    return $posts_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'sk_media_custom_column_filesize', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Display File Size custom column in the Media list table.
 *
 * @param string $column_name Name of the custom column.
 * @param int    $post_id Current Attachment ID.
 */
function sk_media_custom_column_filesize( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'filesize' !== $column_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $bytes = filesize( get_attached_file( $post_id ) );

    echo size_format( $bytes, 2 );
}

add_action( 'admin_print_styles-upload.php', 'sk_filesize_column_filesize' );
/**
 * Adjust File Size column on Media Library page in WP admin
 */
function sk_filesize_column_filesize() {
    echo
    '<style>
        .fixed .column-filesize {
            width: 10%;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this is still working in latest WP as of June 29th 2021.