# sortable custom column in media library

Tags: wp-admin, media-library, columns, sort

trying to make a custom column sortable in the media library. Found lots of examples for posts, and users but can't get them to work on the media library page.

```
function wpse_hook_isv_columns() {
    add_action('manage_media_custom_column', 'isv_custom_media_column_content',10,2);
    add_filter('manage_media_columns', 'isv_custom_media_column_headings');
    add_filter('manage_media_imwidth_sortable_columns', 'imwidth_column_register_sortable' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_hook_isv_columns' );


function isv_custom_media_column_headings($defaults) {
   $defaults['isv_width'] = __( 'Width', 'imwidth' );
   $defaults['isv_height']    = 'Height';
   return $defaults;
}

function isv_custom_media_column_content($column_name,$id) {
   $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
   switch ($column_name) {         
      case 'isv_width':
         $imWidth = get_post_meta($id, "_im_width", true);
         if(  $imWidth ) : 

            echo $imWidth .' ('.$meta['width'].')';
         else : //  add meta value if not there...

            update_post_meta($id, '_im_width', $meta['width']);
            echo $meta['width'].' (updated)';
         endif;          
         break;

      case 'isv_height':
         $desc = get_the_content();
         echo $meta['height'] ? $meta['height'] : $none;
         break;
   }
}

// Register the column as sortable ???
function imwidth_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
          // meta column id => sortby value used in query
          'imwidth'    => 'Width',
    );
    return wp_parse_args($custom, $columns);
}

// This example i found works!

function registerdate($columns) {
    $columns['registerdate'] = __('Registered', 'registerdate');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'registerdate');

function registerdate_columns( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'registerdate' != $column_name )
       return $value;
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $registerdate = $user->user_registered;
    return $registerdate;
}
add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'registerdate_columns', 10, 3);

function registerdate_column_sortable($columns) {
      $custom = array(
      // meta column id => sortby value used in query
      'registerdate'    => 'registered',
      );
  return wp_parse_args($custom, $columns);
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'registerdate_column_sortable' );
```

how can i make isv_width sortable? Any help appreciated!

Comment: thumbs up on the admin users custom registerdate column code, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a sort on the attachment meta data specifically because it's stored in a serialized string.

Whilst `WP_Query` can sort on meta values it can't sort on data that's serialized. For example `wp_get_attachment_metadata` fetches and unserializes that for you inside the column callback, but MySQL queries can't sort on that type of data.

**Short answer:** Not possible due to how the width and height are stored.

---

#### Follow-up:

Of course, if you setup the image height or width as seperate meta values you can then query on that, or should be able to at least, using a couple more hook(in addition to what you have).. `manage_upload_sortable_columns` and `request`.

```
// These would go inside your admin_init hook
add_filter( 'manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'isv_column_register_sortable' );
add_filter( 'request', 'isv_column_orderby' );

function isv_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'Width' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => '_im_width',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}
function isv_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['isv_width'] = 'Width';
    return $columns;
}
```

If it helps more, Scribu gave an example of creating new sortable columns [here](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html). Note, the hook for the media listing is `upload` and not `media` for the sortable columns(because the hook is the screen id).

I tested this alongside your code and it did work, minus the sort order being off, because i don't have the `_im_width` key associated with media in my install.

I hope that's enough info to work from, and be sure to check the link to Scribu's page if you want to see a more complete example of sortable columns.

Comment: ok - now storing width as a meta value '_im_width'. Any idea how can i get the column to worth now? I just can't get the header of the column to be a link...

Comment: Added the necessary info to my answer for you, check it out.. ;)

Comment: you're ace! All works. Had to make one tweak,  && '_im_width' == $vars['orderly'] needed to be  && 'Width' == $vars['orderly']. thanks all. D.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Answer (score 4):

### Full Working Code

```
/*
 * Add Sortable Width and Height Columns to the Media Library
 *
 */

if( is_admin() )
{
    add_filter( 'manage_upload_columns', 'wpse_35680_size_columns_register' );
    add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'wpse_35680_size_columns_display', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'wpse_35680_size_columns_sortable' );
    add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'wpse_35680_update_imagesize_meta_data', 10, 2);
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_35680_size_columns_do_sort' );
}


/*
 * Adding Width and Height columns
 *
 */

function wpse_35680_size_columns_register( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['_width'] = 'Width';
    $columns['_height'] = 'Height';

    return $columns;
}


/*
 * Display the columns
 *
 */

function wpse_35680_size_columns_display( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if( '_width' != $column_name && '_height' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) )
        return;

    list( $url, $width, $height ) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, 'full' );

    if( '_width' == $column_name )
        echo get_post_meta($post_id, '_width', true);

    if( '_height' == $column_name )
        echo get_post_meta($post_id, '_height', true);
}


/*
 * Registering columns as sortable
 *
 */

function wpse_35680_size_columns_sortable( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['_width'] = '_width';
    $columns['_height'] = '_height';

    return $columns;
}


/*
 * Save Image Attachments meta data on save
 *
 */

function wpse_35680_update_image_meta_data( $image_data, $att_id ) 
{
    $width  = $image_data['width'];
    $height = $image_data['height'];

    update_post_meta( $att_id, '_width', $width );
    update_post_meta( $att_id, '_height', $height );

    return $image_data;
}


/*
 * Sort the columns
 *
 */

function wpse_35680_size_columns_do_sort(&$query)
{
    global $current_screen;
    if( 'upload' != $current_screen->id )
        return;
        
    $is_width = (isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && '_width' == $_GET['orderby']);
    $is_height = (isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && '_height' == $_GET['orderby']);
    if( !$is_width && !$is_height )
        return;
    
    if ( '_width' == $_GET['orderby'] ) 
    {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_width');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    }
    
    if ( '_height' == $_GET['orderby'] ) 
    {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_height');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    }   
}
```

---

#### Workaround for Updating All Images in the Posts Table

```
/*
 * Update ALL attachments metada with Width and Height
 *
 * Important: Run Only Once
 * 
 */
//add_action('admin_init','wpse_35680_run_only_once');
function wpse_35680_run_only_once()
{   
    global $wpdb;
    $attachments = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_mime_type LIKE '%image%'" );
    foreach( $attachments as $att )
    {
        list( $url, $width, $height ) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att->ID, 'full' );
        update_post_meta( $att->ID, '_width', $width );
        update_post_meta( $att->ID, '_height', $height );
    }
}
```

---

<sup>*Assembled with the invaluable input from Rarst, Bainternet, kaiser, t31os and scribu throughout this Stack*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First: If you're adding stuff to hooks or filters, you should allways wrap the action calls in a separate function and hook it (in your case:) to `admin_init`:

```
function wpse_hook_isv_columns()
{
    add_action('manage_media_custom_column', 'isv_custom_media_column_content',10,2);
    add_filter('manage_media_columns', 'isv_custom_media_column_headings');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_hook_isv_columns' );
// or:
if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'init', 'wpse_hook_isv_columns' );
```

Else you can't be shure they load early enough.

Also: Why are you calling `$desc = get_the_content();` and not using it?

You should also use a string instead of `None` that is sortable and sort before the number "0" or after the letter "Z". Else it would be - in case of sorting - right in the middle of the sorting results...

Sidenote: If you check the Codex about translation, then you'll see all gettext functions having a second Parameter. That's the *textdomain*, nothing else. So your `__('Width','domain');` will probably have your themes/plugins textdomain, hm? :)

Comment: Thanks Kaiser - updated according to your suggestions but still no joy. Underneath updated code is an example that works on the users page... The column and its values work. I just can't get the width header to be clickable!