# Display image file size in media library

Tags: media-library

This wonderful answer to a related question; that of displaying dimensions in the media library.

[display image size in media library screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30894/display-image-size-in-media-library-screen)

is it possible to use this technique to display the file size as a column? If so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your theme's `functions.php` add the following code to get the file size for all of your items in the *Media* library:

```
add_filter( 'manage_upload_columns', 'wpse_237131_add_column_file_size' );
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'wpse_237131_column_file_size', 10, 2 );

function wpse_237131_add_column_file_size( $columns ) { // Create the column
    $columns['filesize'] = 'File Size';
    return $columns;
}
function wpse_237131_column_file_size( $column_name, $media_item ) { // Display the file size
    if ( 'filesize' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image( $media_item ) ) {
      return;
    }
    $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $media_item ) );
    $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);
    echo $filesize;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't return the file size. It returns a number for instance "809.00 B" and each subsequent entry has a decremented number.

Comment: 809 is the attachment ID

Comment: @ChrisPink Updated my code. May you select my one as the accepted answer instead since I show the complete code instead of yours?

Comment: Of course, how about upvoting my answer too? ;-)

Comment: Not working on WP 4.8 :(

Comment: Hi there. Any suggestions on how to make the column sortable, and to make this code work on newer WP versions? (I've not tested it on new version, but I see someone mentioned it doesn't work in v4.8.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little bit of extra work, change the function above to this;

```
function wpse_237131_column_file_size( $column_name, $media_item ) { // Display the file size
if ( 'filesize' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image( $media_item ) ) {
  return;
}
$filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $media_item ) );
$filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);
echo $filesize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, updated my answer with the full code.